# Check numeric constraint expressions for equivalence/subset of allowed values

Tags: algorithm, haskell, expression, equivalence

I have an AST representing expressions like these:

- `(<=10 && >=3) || ==0`
- `==1 || ==2 || ==3`
- `==1 && !=1`

There are numerics as well as boolean (`||`, `&&`) and numeric (`<`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `>=`, `>`) operators. A boolean `not` operator can be added to the AST if needed. These expressions are used to constrain possible numeric input values (note that the last one does not allow anything).

I am looking for a way of comparing two expressions. I need to know if they allow the exact same set of numbers (are equivalent), or if one expression permits a subset of the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function

```
evaluate :: Expression -> ValueSet
```

that evaluates an expression into a set of values where it is true. This value set could be something like

```
data Value = MinusInfinity | Finite Integer | PositiveInfinity
type Range = (Value, Value)
type ValueSet = [Range]
```

where `ValueSet` is a sorted list of closed, disjoint ranges. Then you can implement the cases of `evaluate` one by one using logic that resembles a sorted merge.

Comment: It also had to work on fractional values so I needed both open and closed interval bounds which made everything more complex - but the approach worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-hard.  Sure feels like it, anyway.

But there might be hope.  As stated, your expression language is pretty darned constrained.  For example, you didn't mention the `not` operator, which means that `&&` can never be converted to `||`.

Here's the outlines of the answer:

1. Normalize the comparison operators:  walk the trees, converting all **<=** to **>** by swapping operands.  At the same time, convert **>=** to **<**.
2. Collapse repeated **and**s and **or**s to 'a multi-operand tree node'.  For example, rewriting `A || ( B || C )` so that it's a single three-operand tree node `or(A,B,C)`.  A node can be collapsed iff it is the same operator as its parent node.
3. Sort the operands `||`, `&&`, `or`, and `and` using a stable sort, so that `C || (B || A)` also collapses to `or(A,B,C)`.  And `B || A` and `A
4. Now that the trees are normalized, a recursive tree comparison works.

This answer doesn't take into account overlapping sets.  For example,
it won't tree the expression